# DDPG always choosing the boundaries actions

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, policy-gradient-descent

Iam trying to implement DDPG algorithm that take a state of 8 values and output action of size=4.
The actions are lower bounded by [5,5,0,0] and upper bounded by [40,40,15,15].

When I train my DDPG it always choose one of the boundaries for example [5,40,0,15] or [40,40,0,0].
I implemented SAC algorithm after that and it works, knowing that I tried my DDPG agent on a gym game and it works. Maybe the problem is with upscaling the actions in the policy agent.

here have a look on the model I have

```
class Buffers:
def __init__(self, buffer_capacity=100000, batch_size=64):
    # Number of "experiences" to store at max
    self.buffer_capacity = buffer_capacity
    num_states = 8
    num_actions = 4
    # Num of tuples to train on.
    self.batch_size = batch_size

    # Its tells us num of times record() was called.
    self.buffer_counter = 0

    # Instead of list of tuples as the exp.replay concept go
    # We use different np.arrays for each tuple element
    self.state_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_states))
    self.action_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_actions))
    self.reward_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, 1))
    self.next_state_buffer = np.zeros((self.buffer_capacity, num_states))

# Takes (s,a,r,s') obervation tuple as input
def record(self, obs_tuple):
    # Set index to zero if buffer_capacity is exceeded,
    # replacing old records
    index = self.buffer_counter % self.buffer_capacity

    self.state_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[0]
    self.action_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[1]
    self.reward_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[2]
    self.next_state_buffer[index] = obs_tuple[3]

    self.buffer_counter += 1




import random
import numpy as np
from collections import deque
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import History 
from keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import keras.backend as K
import import_ipynb
from Noise import OUActionNoise
import tensorflow as tf
keras = tf.keras  
#tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
class DQLearningAgent:
    def __init__(self, seed ,discount_factor =0.95):

        self.tau = 0.05
        self.gamma = discount_factor

        self.critic_lr = 0.002
        self.actor_lr = 0.001
        self.std_dev = [0.7,0.7,0.2,0.2]
        self.buffer = Buffers(50000, 64)
        self.M = 16
        
        self.upper_bound = [40,40,self.M-1 ,self.M-1 ]
        self.lower_bound = [5,5,0,0]
        self.action_scale = (np.array(self.upper_bound) - np.array(self.lower_bound)) / 2.0
        self.action_bias = (np.array(self.upper_bound) + np.array(self.lower_bound)) / 2.0

        
        self._state_size = 8 # unchange
        self._action_size = 4

        self.seed = seed
#         random.seed(self.seed)
#         np.random.seed(self.seed)
        
        self.actor_model = self.get_actor()
        self.critic_model = self.get_critic()
        self.target_actor = self.get_actor()
        self.target_critic = self.get_critic()

        # Making the weights equal initially
        self.target_actor.set_weights(self.actor_model.get_weights())
        self.target_critic.set_weights(self.critic_model.get_weights())
        
        self.critic_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.critic_lr)
        self.actor_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.actor_lr)
        
        
        self.ou_noise = OUActionNoise(mean=np.zeros(self._action_size ), std_deviation=np.array(self.std_dev))
        



    def get_actor(self):
        # Initialize weights between -3e-3 and 3-e3
        last_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=(self._state_size,))
        out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(inputs)
#         out = layers.Dense(28,activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
#         out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
        out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
        outputs = layers.Dense(self._action_size, activation="tanh", kernel_initializer=last_init)(out)
        def antirectifier(x):
            outputs = self.action_scale*x + self.action_bias
            return outputs 
        outputs = layers.Lambda(antirectifier )(outputs)
        model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
        
        return model
    
    def get_critic(self):
        # State as input
        state_input = layers.Input(shape=(self._state_size))
#         state_out = layers.Dense(28, activation="relu")(state_input)


        # Action as input
        action_input = layers.Input(shape=(self._action_size))
#         action_out = layers.Dense(16, activation="relu")(action_input)

        # Both are passed through seperate layer before concatenating
        concat = layers.Concatenate()([state_input, action_input])

        out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(concat)
#         out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
#         out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
        out = layers.Dense(28, activation=keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01))(out)
        outputs = layers.Dense(1)(out)
        # Outputs single value for give state-action
        model = tf.keras.Model([state_input, action_input], outputs)
        return model
    
    
    def learn(self):
        # Get sampling range
        record_range = min(self.buffer.buffer_counter, self.buffer.buffer_capacity)
        # Randomly sample indices
        batch_indices = np.random.choice(record_range, self.buffer.batch_size)
#         print(self.buffer.action_buffer[batch_indices].shape)

        # Convert to tensors
        state_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.buffer.state_buffer[batch_indices])
        action_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.buffer.action_buffer[batch_indices])
        reward_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.buffer.reward_buffer[batch_indices])
        reward_batch = tf.cast(reward_batch, dtype=tf.float32)
        next_state_batch = tf.convert_to_tensor(self.buffer.next_state_buffer[batch_indices])

        return self.update(state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch)
        
        
    def update(self, state_batch, action_batch, reward_batch, next_state_batch):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            target_actions_new = self.target_actor(next_state_batch)
            y = reward_batch + self.gamma * self.target_critic([next_state_batch,target_actions_new])
            q = self.critic_model([state_batch,action_batch])
            critic_loss = tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.math.square(y - q))
        critic_grad = tape.gradient(critic_loss, self.critic_model.trainable_variables)
        self.critic_optimizer.apply_gradients( zip(critic_grad, self.critic_model.trainable_variables))
        
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            actions = self.actor_model(state_batch)
            critic_value = self.critic_model([state_batch , actions])
            actor_loss = -tf.math.reduce_mean(critic_value)
        actor_grad = tape.gradient(actor_loss , self.actor_model.trainable_variables)
        self.actor_optimizer.apply_gradients( zip(actor_grad, self.actor_model.trainable_variables))
        
        self.update_target(self.target_actor.variables , self.actor_model.variables)
        self.update_target(self.target_critic.variables , self.critic_model.variables)   
        
        return actor_loss,critic_loss
    
    
    def update_target(self,target_weights, weights):
        for (a, b) in zip(target_weights, weights):
            a.assign(b * self.tau + a * (1 - self.tau))
    

    def policy(self,state):
        sampled_actions = tf.squeeze(self.actor_model(state))
        noise = self.ou_noise()
        # Adding noise to action
        sampled_actions = sampled_actions.numpy() + noise

        # We make sure action is within bounds
        legal_action = np.clip(sampled_actions, self.lower_bound, self.upper_bound)

        return [np.squeeze(legal_action)]
```

Comment: I have encountered the same behavior, and solved it using config from stable_baseline_3's DDPG, have you any news?

Comment: I am facing similar problem! don't know what to do